# How to scrobble Google Music to Last.fm?

Tags: google-workspace, google-chrome-extensions, last.fm, google-play-music, firefox-extensions

Is there a way to scrobble my music from Google Music to last.fm?

I tried some extensions which did not work for Chromium (sorry for the vagueness, but I don't remember which I tried) so I was wondering if anyone had set something up which worked for them.

I don't mind if I have to use a certain browser, e.g. Firefox, Chrome, Opera -- as long as it works.

Comment: so sad g music won't do it through an API like rdio...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Last.fm Scrobbler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hhinaapppaileiechjoiifaancjggfjm) as Chrome extension. 11,862 users. It should work. Sorry, being in India, couldn't try it out.

Comment: I've used this extension and found it to work well.