# How to sync Last.fm loved tracks with Google Music liked

Tags: synchronization, google-play-music, last.fm

Google Music has a nice feature to automatically download the liked tracks. I have a long history of loved tracks in Last.fm and want to have them all in my devices. I'm also using MusicBee in my desktop computer, and would like to have my liked Google Music as loved songs there.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23730/how-to-scrobble-google-music-to-last-fm